# How to escape hex values in netcat

Tags: netcat

I want to send the following via netcat:

```
99||0x00
```

(4 ASCII characters and a zero)

How is this done? I'm using Windows XP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

```
# echo -ne "99||\x00" | nc <host> <port>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!  Helped me to answer my own question and get my software working.  Thanks

Comment: OP said Windows, not *nix.

Answer (score 4):

Put the bytes into a file with binary editor and pipe it to netcat. Windows shell too supports input from file redirection via

```
netcat (options) < (file)
```

Alternatively, you may be able to input it with keyboard directly via Alt-000, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your Unix flavor you can try one of these

```
echo '99||#' | tr '#' '\000' | netcat <host> <port>

echo -e '99||\000' | netcat <host> <port>
```

Comment: OP requested help for windows xp not Linux.