# How to write a packet to TAP interface in C?

Tags: c, linux, networking, driver

Does any one know how to write a packet into a  TAP interface in C? Or any other language?

I have constructed an Ethernet datagram by myself, and I want to write it to a specific tap interface.

Thanks! :)

About TAP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP

Comment: Thank you for your comment:) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP

Comment: You should probably stick with your original question and probably give more information on what you are trying to accomplish. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732586/linux-how-to-send-a-whole-packet-to-a-specific-port-on-another-host

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you've created a TAP interface already (using `ip tuntap add`), you can use a **Packet Socket** to write data into it (try `man 7 packet` for more info).

To start with, use `int sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_ALL))` to create a packet socket.

The second step is to find the **interface index** (`ifindex`) of the TAP interface. Just run the command `ip link` and note down the number at the beginning of each line. For instance,

```
[nav@blumarine Test02]$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: p12p1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:26:b9:24:82:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:17:fe:8c:f7:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

the ifindex of `lo` will be 1 and that of `eth0` will be 3.

The third step is to fill in a `sockaddr_ll` structure to pass to the `sendto()` api. This structure is used to hold the info about your packet's destination address. Fill it exactly this way:

```
struct sockaddr_ll SendSockAddr;
SendSockAddr.sll_family   = AF_PACKET;
SendSockAddr.sll_halen    = ETH_ALEN;
SendSockAddr.sll_ifindex  = ifindex;   // The number we just found earlier..
SendSockAddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
SendSockAddr.sll_hatype   = 0;
SendSockAddr.sll_pkttype  = 0;
```

And finally, use `sendto()` to send your packet out. Use `man 3 sendto` for more info on `sendto()` and `man 7 packet` for more insight into `struct sockaddr_ll`.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found I can use send_packet() function in libpcap, which also calls sendto().