# Eventmachine: Escapes received binary data

Tags: ruby, binary, eventmachine

I'm using EventMachine tutorial as a starting point to experiment with sending / receiving binary data.  The sample code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems' # or use Bundler.setup
require 'eventmachine'

class EchoServer < EM::Connection
  def receive_data(data)
    puts data
    send_data(data)
  end
end

EventMachine.run do
  # hit Control + C to stop
  Signal.trap("INT")  { EventMachine.stop }
  Signal.trap("TERM") { EventMachine.stop }

  EventMachine.start_server("0.0.0.0", 10000, EchoServer)
end
```

I use telent to connect to the EM server

```
telent -8 localhost:10000
```

I send the following data to the EM server:

```
\x17\xEB\xB3\b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x89Bo\xAF
```

EM prints out this:

```
\\x17\\xEB\\xB3\\b\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x89Bo\\xAF\r\n
```

For some reason, it's escaping the slashes and adding `\r\n` to the received data.

How do I stop EM from escaping the data and just accept raw binary that's sent to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the culprit is telnet.  I solved this using netcat.

The command is from this question: [How to escape hex values in netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553572/how-to-escape-hex-values-in-netcat)

```
echo "\x17\xEB\xB3\b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x89Bo\xAF" | nc localhost 10000
```